# Get customer account data in shipment PDF

Tags: shipment, pdf, customer-account

In the Invoice PDF I can get (logged in) customer account data with the following code:

```
$customer_email = $order->getCustomerEmail();
$customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer"); 
$customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId()); 
$customer->loadByEmail($customer_email);
```

If I try to use this code in the shipment PDF (Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Shipment.pdf), the customer data remains empty.

Given the customer email in $order, how can I get the account data in the shipment PDF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use `$order->getCustomerId()` instead of `getCustomerEmail`.  Then you can just load the customer like this:

```
$customerId = $order->getCustomerId();
if ($customerId) { //the order was not placed as guest
    Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
}
else {
    //order was placed as guest.
}
```

Doing it like this, you won't need to set a website id to the customer model before loading it.

Answer (score 1):

Since the PDF is created from the backend the current Website ID will be 0 (admin).
Depending on in what method you are trying to use your code snippet you might want to do something like this:

`function getPdf`

```
$customer_email = $order->getCustomerEmail();
$customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer"); 
$customer->setWebsiteId($shipment->getStore()->getWebsite()->getId()); 
$customer->loadByEmail($customer_email);
```

I'm using the `getStore()` data from the `shipment` object. This way it gets the store the order was placed from.

Comment: On the third line I get the following error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object`. As @Marius solutions works, this is not relevant to me anymore, but still wanted to give feedback.

Comment: @SPRBRN thank you for the feedback. Ill look into it later on to correct the answer

Comment: @SanderMangel. Fixed it. It was `getWebsiteId()` but should be `getWebsite()`